# Radio button not working (Can select multiple radio buttons at a time)

Tags: html, radio-button

I have the following HTML:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Sys/Prod/Proc :</td>
        <td width="10px"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="A"/></td>
        <td width="10px"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="10px"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub-Sys/Prod/Proc :</td>
        <td width="10px"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="B"/></td>
        <td width="10px"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="10px"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Component :</td>
        <td width="10px"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="C"/></td>
        <td width="10px"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The radio buttons I have is not working as expected. Now I can select multiple radio buttons instead of one at a time. How can I fix that?

Comment: This is expected behavior if multiple radio inputs have a different `name` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each radio button needs to have the same `name` attribute for them to act in a mutually exclusive manner.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Sys/Prod/Proc :</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="A" /></td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="10px"></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sub-Sys/Prod/Proc :</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="B" /></td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="10px"></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Component :</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="C" /></td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```